# Does crontab day of week and day of month must both be matched at the same time?

Tags: cron

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron?oldformat=true#Overview) says:

> While normally the job is executed when the time/date specification
>   fields all match the current time and date, there is one exception: if
>   both "day of month" (field 3) and "day of week" (field 5) are
>   restricted (not "*"), then one or both must match the current day.[3]

Does this means if I set

day of week = 2 and day of month = 09

OR

day of week = 3 and day of month = 10

then the task won't run on 2019/Jan/09 (Wednesday)?

I think the wiki is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means if one of the two conditions is satisfied (can be both, does not need to be)

> **Note:** The day of a command's execution can be specified in the following two fields — 'day of month', and 'day of week'.  If both fields are restricted (i.e., do not contain the `*` character), the command will be run when
>          **either** field matches the current time.  For example,
>          `30 4 1,15 * 5` would cause a command to be run at 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, **plus** every Friday.
>
> **<sub>source: `man 5 crontab`</sub>**

In the examples of the OP, if the day is `Wednesday Jan 09 2019`, than the crontab:

```
x x 9 x 2
```

will execute because it is the nineth day of the month, and

```
x x 10 x 3
```

will execute because it is a Wednesday

Answer (score 2):

The function between day of month and day of week is OR. So the records

```
0 0 9 1 2
```

and

```
0 0 10 1 3
```

both will execute the script. The relation is

```
day of week OR day of month
```

For reference check [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) of `cron`

> Note: The day of a command's execution can be specified by two fields
>   - day of month, and day of week. If both fields are restricted (ie, aren't *), the command will be run when either field matches the
>   current time.